# I'm using android API level 19 then also getting error for Notification

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, notifications

I'm getting `he constructor Notification(int, CharSequence, long) is deprecated` when I try to use it in API level 19

For notification I did the code like following

```
@Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  nm = (NotificationManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  CharSequence from = "Nithin";
  CharSequence message = "Crazy About Android...";
  PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
    new Intent(), 0);
  Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
    "Crazy About Android...", System.currentTimeMillis());
  notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
  nm.notify(1, notif);
 }

AlarmManager am ;
      public void setOneTimeAlarm() {
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
          PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
          am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000), pendingIntent);
         }

         public void setRepeatingAlarm() {
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
          PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
          am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
            (5 * 1000), pendingIntent);
         }

Inside onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState){
    am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
          setOneTimeAlarm();
```

> Getting error for Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
>           "Crazy About Android...", System.currentTimeMillis());

`The constructor Notification(int, CharSequence, long) is deprecated` why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs

> public Notification (int icon, CharSequence tickerText, long when)
>
> Added in API level 1 This constructor was deprecated in API level 11.
>   Use Notification.Builder instead.

I guess its a lint warning that you are using a constructor that is deprecated.

So use Notification.Builder.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html

Exmaple @

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Answer (score 2):

you can use `NotificationBuilder` available in `support.v4` or `support.v13` library

here

```
     private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
     mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                    this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

     Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewMovie_Details.class);         

        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);     

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(msg)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentText("Yuhu New Notification");

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(alarmIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: thanks but unable to set notification after every interval I used alarmManager check question updated code

Comment: @ashuthinks then you've have to use sample from developers here http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html, anyways yesterday i finished the same you're asking right now, but it's somewhat lengthy i can't post it here.

Comment: thanks i'm getting error in ur snippet The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type TimeAlarm :(

Comment: might be i did it in a different way you should check it http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html

Answer (score 1):

They added Notification.Builder and want you to use that instead.  That doesn't mean that using the old way won't work.  If you're getting the expected result I'd probably ignore this, but understand that there may be better ways of rewriting your code in the future.